# Message_filters TimeSequencer compile error

Tags: ros-kinetic, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am trying to use the TimeSequencer filter of the message_filters library to introduce a delay to a certain topic. I have created a simple example following the documentation on http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h"
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_sequencer.h>

void chatterCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("Msg received");

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> sub(n, "chatter", 1);
  message_filters::TimeSequencer<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> seq(sub, ros::Duration(0.1), ros::Duration(0.01), 10);
  seq.registerCallback(chatterCallback);
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

However, I get a compilation error stating " undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()' ". Here is the whole compilation error message:

```
CMakeFiles/Subscriber.dir/src/Subscriber.cpp.o: In function `message_filters::TimeSequencer<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >::~TimeSequencer()':
Subscriber.cpp:(.text._ZN15message_filters13TimeSequencerIN13geometry_msgs12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEED2Ev[_ZN15message_filters13TimeSequencerIN13geometry_msgs12PoseStamped_ISaIvEEEED5Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()'
```

Does anyone know where the error comes from? I have searched for more documentation but I haven't found a solution. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance,

Ignacio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323115/message_filters-timesequencer-compile-error/) by [iabadia](https://answers.ros.org/users/37308/iabadia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> However, I get a compilation error stating

> ```
> undefined reference to `message_filters::Connection::disconnect()'
> ```

"undefined reference" errors are never compilation errors, but *linker errors*.

It's likely you're not (correctly) linking to the `message_filters` libraries.

If you can show us your `CMakeLists.txt` we can check it for you.

Note: please remove all the boilerplate comments from the file before you post it here, they're not needed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iabadia](https://answers.ros.org/users/37308/iabadia/) on 2019-05-14**:
You are right, stupid mistake, I didn't add the message_filters libraries in the CMakeLists.txt.
Problem solved, thanks!!